# Formview is switching to edit mode

Tags: asp.net

I have a formview which is based on a number search from a textbox, you enters the number you want to lookup and the record is shown in readonly mode, and you have the possibility to edit og add a new record.
Everythings works okay the first time, end search completes and the data i shown in readonlymenu, buttons for add and edit works.
If I don't do anything and just search a new number while the previous record are shown, then the form enters insert mode, it should just show the new data in read only instead, so I have to cancel and then search again.

```
The formview tag looks lige this:
        <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" OnItemInserting="FormView1_ItemInserting" AllowPaging="True" BackColor="#F2D7D5" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" DataKeyNames="Id">
```

Any ideas why it behaves like this?
Regards
Zorglub

I've tried to play around with this properties in formview and the textbox input that is used to select which data is displayed, but the result is the same, the first number I enter in the textbox works fine, the data is displayed correctly in readonly mode, with the options to edit or add a new. When I enter number two in the textbox the form changes to editmode.
Protected Sub FormView1_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As FormViewPageEventArgs) Handles FormView1.PageIndexChanging
FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.ReadOnly)
End Sub

```
Protected Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.ReadOnly)
End Sub
```